# Mule message.payload and payload

Tags: mule

I have a Mule Expression Language expression:

```
<set-payload value="#[message.payload.hasNext() ? message.payload.next(): null]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
<choice  doc:name="Choice">
  <when expression="#[message.payload != null]">
```

I am trying to iterate over a `ConsumerIterator` and am getting the error

```
Execution of the expression "message.payload.hasNext() ? message.payload.next(): null" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException)
org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionLanguage:202 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/expression/ExpressionRuntimeException.html)
6. Execution of the expression "message.payload.hasNext() ? message.payload.next(): null" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: ConsumerIterator (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException)
org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer:135 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerMessagingException.html)
```

My solution to this is to rewrite the code without the `message.` prefix:

```
<set-payload value="#[payload.hasNext() ? payload.next(): null]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
<choice  doc:name="Choice">
  <when expression="#[payload is NullPayload]">
```

1. What is the difference between #[message.payload] and #[payload]?
2. If `payload` is an instance of `NullPayload` why doesn't `payload.hasNext()` throw an `Exception`?

From what I've read the best practice is to use `#[message.payload]` instead of `#[payload]`.

I am using Mule 3.6.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by assigning `set-payload` to `false` or an empty `String` instead of `null`:

```
<set-payload value="#[message.payload.hasNext() ? message.payload.next(): 'none']" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
```

Even assigning `null` is not valid in batch-steps process, it is better to assign some other `String`. Now I am able to use `#[message.payload]`:

```
<logger message="Query: #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between `message.payload` and `payload`. Payload is a shortcut left there just for compatibility with Mule 2.

From time to time there is an issue here and there about a difference between one and the other, just small nuisances but in this case I believe you should try `message.payload is NullPayload`.

Comment: If there is no value, will my #[payload.hasNext() ? payload.next(): null] become null or NullPayload if there is no value?.  I have to use payload is NullPayload condition, not message.payload is nullpayload which throws exception again.